# I don't understand functional equations. A complicated question.

Tags: functions

> We are given the following:
>
> $f(x)=5x+3$
>
> $g(2x−1)=x−3$.
>
> We have to find:
>
> $f^{-1}∘g(x) = ?$

I have the solution to the problem, but I don't understand two things:

1. In order to solve for $g(x)$, we need to have substitution where $t = 2x-1$, and then plug that $x$ onto $x-3$. Why? Given my understanding of functions, it's more logical to me that we should just plug $2x-1$ into $x-3$, so we get $g(x) = (2x-1)-3$.
2. Later on in the exercise, after we find $g(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$, we are faced with what, for me, seems like the same problem from above. Yet we solve it differently. Here is what I mean:

$$f^{-1}(g(x)) = f^{-1}(\frac{x-5}{2}) = \frac{ \frac{x-5}{2}-3 }{5} $$

Why do we in case (2) simply plug $\frac{x-5}{2}$ into $x$, while in case (1) we need to substitute with $t$ and then plug into $x$? Apologies for the complexity.

Comment: hint:  $$g(\color{blue}{2x-1}) = x-3 = \dfrac{\color{blue}{2x-1}-5}{2}$$

Comment: So we are essentially trying to find what numbers to plug into the right side so we can get g(x) on the left. I feel I understand more now. But why don't we do it the same way for case (2)?

Comment: In the first case, you are not given $g(x)$ directly. You just have $g(2x-1)$, so you have to do some work figuring out $g(x)$

Comment: In the second case, you know $f^{-1}(x)$. So to find something like $f^{-1}(\heartsuit)$, you simply replace $x$ by $\heartsuit$ in $f^{-1}(x)$

Comment: Alright, so if I understand, the operation of $(f o g)$ is in principle not the same as $g(2x-1) = x-3$?

How are the two operations different? As far as I see, in both cases we have something we don't want in the left parentheses, so we try to get only $x$ there.

By the way, thank you for your helpful answers

Comment: In first case you're finding  $g(x)$ from $g(2x-1)$.
In second case you're finding $f^{-1}(\frac{x-5}{2})$ from $f^{-1}(x)$. See the difference?

Comment: Boom, now I got it. The two operations are basically inverses of each other. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about how $g$ works:

- $g(2\cdot 7 - 1) = 7-3$. This means $g(13)=4$
- $g(2\cdot 8 - 1) = 8-3$. This means $g(15)=5$
- $g(2\cdot 9 - 1) = 9-3$. This means $g(17)=6$
- $g(2\cdot 10 - 1) = 10-3$. This means $g(19)=7$

The rule is that $g(2\cdot\square - 1) = \square - 3$.

Now focus on the list of values on the right. We have shown how to get $g(13)$, $g(15)$, $g(17$), and $g(19)$.

Suppose I want to determine the value of $g(31)$, but I don't want to continue the pattern and compute everything in between.

If I knew what to put into "$\square$" so that "$2\cdot\square-1$" was the number $31$, then the answer would just be "$\square-4$".

What I need to know, in other words, is how to solve "$2\cdot\square-1 = 31$" for "$\square$". But you can do that: just add $1$ to both sides and divide by $2$. That just means "$\square = \tfrac{31+1}{2}$".

There's nothing special about $31$. To find $g(N)$, you get $\square = \tfrac{N+1}{2}$ so that $g(N)=\square-3= \tfrac{N+1}{2} -3$.

$N$ here is just a placeholder. You can call it $x$ or $y$ or whatever. In particular, $\boxed{g(x)=\tfrac{x+1}{2} -3}$.

Now can you apply similar reasoning for the second part of the question?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you for the beautiful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be consistent in your substitutions. If you replace $x$ in
$$
g(2x-1)=x-3
$$
with $t=2x-1$, you need to do it on both sides simultaneously,
$$
g(2(2x-1)-1)=(2x-1)-3,
$$
which does not simplify the situation.

What you want is to replace $2x-1$ with $t$ or $x$ with $\frac{t+1}2$. This leads then directly to the given solution
$$
g(t)=\frac{t-5}2,
$$
where you now can, again simultaneously on both sides, replace the variable name $t$ with $x$.

Comment: No no, I perfectly understand that. But I'm asking why do we do it in case 1 and not case 2? Thank you for your answer, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: But you understand why $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-3}5$? Then replace $x$ with $g(x)$ on both sides and then expand the expression for $g(x)$ on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

Let's find the inverse of $f$ first. Solving for $x$, we find that $x = \frac{f(x) - 3}{5}$. "Renaming" variables gives you $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x - 3}{5}$. Now, to find the expression for $g(x)$, we need to perform a change of variables. Let $x^* = 2x - 1$. Then $x = \frac{x^{*} + 1}{2}$. Substituting this into the expression for $g$, you get $g(x^{*}) = \frac{x^{*} + 1}{2} - 3 = \frac{x^{*} - 5}{2}$. Now, substitute this expression into $f^{-1}(x)$, and you get $f^{-1}(g(x)) = \frac{1}{5} \times (\frac{x - 5}{2} - 3) = \frac{x - 11}{10}$.